# how to do addition dataframe of different type of TImestamp columns in python

Tags: python, pandas

below is my dataframe and I want to do an addition operation which i have mentioned down.

```
a                            b
0 days 19:18:43.997000       4
0 days 19:18:44.039000       4
```

`b` is a result of `df['time:timestamp'].dt.dayofweek`.

when i do following code `df['a'] + (df['b'] * 3600 * 24)`, it throws `TypeError: Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays with TimedeltaArray is no longer supported.  Instead of adding/subtracting` n`, use n * obj.freq`

type of a -: Timedelta('0 days 19:18:43.997000')

type of b -: numpy.int64

can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `b` back to timedelta:

```
df['a'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['b'], unit='d')
```

Or

```
df['a'] + df['b'] * pd.Timedelta('1D')
```

Output:

```
0   4 days 19:18:43.997000
1   4 days 19:18:44.039000
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```